# Can't convert form data to URL

Tags: http, post

I'm trying to send a POST request to get a file downloaded, but I'm having problem complete this operation using URL.

The form looks like this:

```
<FORM action='download.php' method='post' encType='multipart/form-data'>
    <TD bgcolor="white" valign="top" style="padding:10px;">
    <TABLE cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width='100%'>
    <TR>
        <TD width='30%' align='center'>
            Uploaded torrent code (date+hash):<BR>
            <INPUT size=58 name="ref" value="1333f4f84bb41d5adc0f61e8f5a4658460da70b2737" style="font-size:10px;"><INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="reff" value="MTM3OTU2Mjk4OQ=="><BR>
            downloaded: 27988<BR>
            <INPUT type="submit" height=27 width=174 value=download border=0 name=submit valign="bottom" onclick="setpos(1);">
        </TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
    </TD>
</FORM>
```

So I tried to use URL:

```
www.site.com/download.php?ref=1333f4f84bb41d5adc0f61e8f5a4658460da70b2737
```

but that doesn't work. Chrome seems to show me a browser based form data:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryeqA3pQupG0ndfLMZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ref"

1333f4f84bb41d5adc0f61e8f5a4658460da70b2737
------WebKitFormBoundaryeqA3pQupG0ndfLMZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="reff"

MTM3OTQ4NzQwMQ==
------WebKitFormBoundaryeqA3pQupG0ndfLMZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

download
------WebKitFormBoundaryeqA3pQupG0ndfLMZ--
```

What should I do now?

Comment: `multipart/form-data` can't be put in the URL.

Comment: You can't put parameters in the URL if the server script isn't expecting them there. If it's PHP and uses `$_POST`, it requires the parameters to be in the `POST` body.

Comment: See this for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045097/php-redirect-and-send-data-via-post

Answer (score 0):

**Post request can't be made in browser url.**

-> This is is first way to do this

**Sample post request using curl:**

```
curl -F param1=val1 -F param2=val2 -F param3=val3  http://host:port/abc.json
```

**Hit this in terminal/console/cmd**

```
curl -F ref=1333f4f84bb41d5adc0f61e8f5a4658460da70b2737  www.site.com/download.php
```

-> Or install **RestConsole** in chrome browser using Google Web Store. There you can handle every kind of request.