# Separate forms, 2 actions in specific order

Tags: php, forms, submit

I've got a form asking for user input.  The input should be a name which exists in my database.

```
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
</form>
```

I'm trying to first check user input, and then if the input is clean, send the user off to another site.

This is what I'm using to scrub the input:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would like to send to the next site after querying to my database and receiving an ID:

```
<form action = "http://website.com/~username/site.php" method="get">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <Input type="submit">
</form>
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: So you want to redirect the user if his name is within your database table? Use phps header() function to do so.

Comment: I've tried doing that.  Where should i be putting the header() function?  When I tried it, it didn't seem to execute.

Comment: To redirect a user use header('Location: myfile.php').

Comment: Okay so that works well.  Now I need to also be able to send that ID I get form a query to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Use header() function to achieve your goal

```
header('Location: yourfile.php?id=' . $yourIdValue); // adopt to your needs
```

In your target script fetch id with

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with $_POST?

Comment: Using $_POST is possible but more complicated. Why prefer post over get?

Comment: For security reasons, to keep people from editing the URL to access another ID.  How much more complicated?

Comment: POST is nor more secure than GET. If you wanna use POST, have a look at these examples (using curl): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045097/php-redirect-and-send-data-via-post